# using sed to replace with wildcards

Tags: unix, sed

I am trying to replace this text (whatever the xxxx) :

```
{"type":"record","name":"xxxx","namespace":"example","fields":[{"name":"name","type":"string"}, {"name":"favorite_color","type":["string","null"]}]}
```

with this one:

```
{"type":"record","name":"yyyy","namespace":"example","fields":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"favorite_color","type":["string","null"]}]}
```

I am using sed, but with this command:

```
sed 's/\"name\"\:\".*\"/\"name\"\:\"yyyy\"/' file.json
```

I am getting:

```
{"type":"record", "name":"yyyy"]}]}
```

because it replaces all the content until the last double quote.

How could I use the wildcards to replace only the text until the next double quote?

Comment: if this is `json` data, better to use parser like `jq`... for ex: `jq -c '.name = "yyyy"'`

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
sed 's/\"name\":\"[^\"]*\"/\"name\":\"yyyy\"/' file.json
```

Hence, modify the regular pattern so it looks until the next double quotes instead of any character.

If you want to write the changes to the file, you'll need `-i` flag, in addition to `-r` flag to use regular expressions. And if you want this to be applied to multiple occurrences, you can add a `g` to the sed command:

```
sed -i -r 's/\"name\":\"[^\"]*\"/\"name\":\"yyyy\"/g' file.json
```

**Update**: not needed to escape double quotes... The command could be just this:

```
sed -i -r 's/"name":"[^"]*"/"name":"yyyy"/g' file.json
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it works as I need

Comment: No need to escape double quote is not needed here , because its start using single quotes, Single quote treated as literal value. `sed 's/"name":"[^"]\+/"name":"yyyy"/'`

Comment: So you mean that it is not needed to escape the double quotes? That's right, it could be just this:      sed 's/"name":"[^"]*"/"name":"yyyy"/g' . Updating the answer...

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Comment: And this is enough sed 's/\(name":"\)[^"]*/\1yyyy/'